# Why is the recursive function returning undefined on return array?

Tags: javascript

I have a simple algorithm I'm working on, return the smallest number using recursion. Everything seems to be right and working, except that when I return the numbers array at the end, it comes back as undefined.

```
function findSmallestInt(numbers) {
  var updatedArr = [];
  if (numbers[0] < numbers[1]) {
    numbers.splice(1, 1);
    if (numbers.length > 1) {
      findSmallestInt(numbers);
    } else {
      return numbers;
    }
  } else {
    numbers.splice(0, 1);
    if (numbers.length > 1) {
      findSmallestInt(numbers);
    } else {
      return numbers;
    }
  }
}

console.log(findSmallestInt([78, 56, 232, 12, 18]));
```

Comment: You forgot to `return` the recursive calls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Math.min()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min):

```js
console.log([Math.min(...[78, 56, 232, 12, 18])]);
```

And for your recursive function, as previously pointed out in the comments by [@CertainPerformance](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9515207/certainperformance), you should `return` the  `findSmallestInt(number)` function result:

```js
function findSmallestInt(numbers) {
  numbers.splice(numbers[0] < numbers[1] ? 1 : 0, 1);
  return numbers.length > 1 ? findSmallestInt(numbers) : numbers;
}

console.log(findSmallestInt([78, 56, 232, 12, 18]));
```